# KeyDown event on JQuery draggable does not trigger

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, keyboard-shortcuts, jquery-ui-draggable

I dynamically add draggable elements and i can delete them via a dropzone. Now I want to add the possibility to delete them via a keypress.
I tried with this code:

```
$('.draggable').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 46) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Any ideas why this doesnt't work?

Comment: As the target for the event is dynamically created, the problem can almost definitely be solved through event delegation. Please read the documentation for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more information.

Comment: It also does not work on static elements

Answer (score 0):

you could try passing your input with the search class as an argument to the .on() method like below:

```
$('document').on('keydown', '.draggable', function(e) {
       alert("Method Hit");
       if(e.keyCode == 46) {
            console.log($this);
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This gives me the same results. Thanks anyway.

Comment: have you put a console log in the event to confirm that the event is not firing? This looks to be the correct solution.

Comment: as Rich says have you tried either using console.log or old school alerts or debugger statements with Developer Tools

Comment: @MikeW - I added some debugging you could try - use Developer Tools and make sure $this is the correct element - and that the alert fires when you hit the keydown

Comment: I utilized the devTools but the alert is not called. And logically neither the logs

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem. @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat is on the right path, but the event for keydown on the class `.draggable` doesn't make sense. As this is for jQueryUI draggable, these events will only trigger if `.draggable` is the currently focused class. Which probably won't happen when you want it to.

I think you may want to add the event handler to the document, but without specifying the draggable class.

```
$('document').on('keydown', function(e) {
   alert("Method Hit");
   if(e.keyCode == 46) {
        console.log("Remove the draggable class now");
        $(".draggable").remove();
    }
});
```

Of course, this approach will apply the event to the entire document, so if you hit delete, *any* element with class draggable will be deleted. If that is ok with you, then this will work. If you wanted to perform targetted removal, you could apply an on-click to add a class, then have the keydown remove the last clicked .draggable.